# C# How do I interact with two generated controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I have a `Checkbox`, when marked it will create a `Listbox`, `Button` and a `Textbox`.
The generated `Button`, should have the `Click` event to fill the *generated* `Listbox` with the value of the *generated* `Textbox`.

But I get **compile time error** inside `public System.Windows.Forms.Button AddNewButton()` :

> The name Txb does nost exist in the current context
>
> The name lb does nost exist in the current context

Here is the code:

```
 private void cbDd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewListBox();
        AddNewTextBox();
        AddNewButton();
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox AddNewListBox()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.Controls.Add(lb);
        lb.Top = 74;
        lb.Left = 500;
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        return lb;
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txb = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txb);
        txb.Top = 180;
        txb.Left = 500;
        txb.Text = "item name";
        cLeft = cLeft + 1;
        return txb;
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.Button AddNewButton()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Button btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Top = 210;
        btn.Left = 500;
        btn.Text = "Add item";
        btn.Click += (s, e) => { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txb.Text)) return;
                };
        lb.Items.Add(cbTxb.Text);
        return btn;
    }
```

Comment: Is your question how to pass value between two methods? Try to use method parameters and fields.

Comment: No I don't think that would work, when I generate these controls and I try to activate my click event the txb won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `AddNew`(`ListBox|TextBox|Button`)

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox AddNewListBox()
{
    return new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox() {
      Location = new Point(500, 74),
      parent   = this, // instead of this.Controls.Add(...)
    };
}

public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
{
    return new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox() {
      Location = new Point(500, 180), 
      Text     = "item name",
      Parent   = this, 
    }; 
}

public System.Windows.Forms.Button AddNewButton() 
{
    return new System.Windows.Forms.Button() {
      Location = new Point(500, 210),
      Text     = "Add item",  
      Parent   = this,  
    };
}
```

I suggest implementing `AddNewControls()` where created controls can *interact* with one another:

```
private void AddNewControls() {
  var lb  = AddNewListBox();
  var txb = AddNewTextBox();
  var btn = AddNewButton();

  btn.Click += (s, e) => {
    // now btn (button) can use txb (TextBox)
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txb.Text)) 
      return;

    //TODO: put relevant code here
  }   

  cLeft += 3;

  //TODO: check lb and cbTxb.Text
  lb.Items.Add(cbTxb.Text);
}
```

Then you can put

```
private void cbDd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    AddNewControls();
}
```